# Python Storm ORM, how to work with time field types

Tags: python, mysql, orm

According to this table https://storm.canonical.com/Manual#Table_of_properties_vs._python_vs._database_types, working with MySQL Time fields, you have to use python's time type.

And how would I do that?

Let's say I want to save 9:30, or anything in the database...

```
    import time
    storm_object = StormObject()
    storm_object.time = time.time() #this raises TypeError: Expected time, found 11... (some number)
    storm_object.time = time.strptime('9:30') #this raises TypeError: Expected time, found time.struct_time...
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I was using the wrong module... Not very straight forward behind python newbie's eyes:

```
    import date
    storm_object = StormObject()
    storm_object.time = datetime.time(9, 30)
    store.add(storm_object)
```